# Two li elements position one left and the other right

Tags: html, css

I have a `ul` with two `li`, the first is a descriptive element, the second is a "close" element (with a simple X ico for closing):

```
<div class="video-button-list top">  
    <ul>
        <li id="video-file-title">FileName</li>
        <li id="video-close-button">X</li>
    </ul>  
</div>
```

My goal is to have the first `li` centered in the containing `div` and the second floating right so that it appears in the top right corner of the page (really what that means to you is floating right in the `div`).

[image]

```
.video-button-list.top ul,
.video-button-list.top ul li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

 .video-button-list.top ul {
     left: 50%;
 }

.video-button-list.top ul li {
    line-height: 55px;
    right: 50%;
}

#video-close-button {
    float: right;
}
```

The list, itself, is `display: inline-block`. I have three related questions:

1. Is this styling possible with the current structure of my HTML
2. If so, what changes do I need to make to achieve the desired styling?
3. If not, what is the recommended structure and associated styling?

Comment: Why the down vote? What can I do to improve the question? I've been working on the solution for a while and would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably use text-alignment, which doesn't depend on approximate margins, and absolute positioning for the close button:

```css
.video-button-list.top ul,
.video-button-list.top ul li {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.video-button-list.top ul li {
    line-height: 55px;
    list-style: none;
}
.video-button-list.top ul li:last-child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-button-list top">
    <ul>
        <li id="video-file-title">FileName</li>
        <li id="video-close-button">X</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I mentioned the margin--the other answer takes a guess at what will roughly center your first list item. It also seems simpler to me.

Comment: Woah, you are fast! `:)`

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes it is possible.
2. You dont have to position the ul as relative or float left, just float right the second item.

Here is how I did (lil hacky with the margin-left):

HTML:

```
 <body>
      <div class="wrapper">
      <ul>
        <li class="list-item item1">ITEM 1</li>
        <li class="list-item item2">ITEM 2</li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </body>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
}

li{
  display: inline-block;
}

.item1{
  margin-left: 40%;
}

.item2{
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: Worked well, thanks. I like the simplicity. That's what I get for reading a bunch of other junk! Don't know why I keep getting the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

It is really a right way and scenario to use `position`ing for this:

```css
.video-button-list.top ul,
.video-button-list.top ul li {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
.video-button-list.top ul li {
  line-height: 55px;
  list-style: none;
}
.video-button-list.top ul li#video-close-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 5px;
  margin-top: -1em;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-button-list top">
  <ul>
    <li id="video-file-title">FileName</li>
    <li id="video-close-button">&times;</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `flexbox`.

```css
.video-button-list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.video-button-list ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#video-close-button {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-button-list top">
  <ul>
    <li id="video-file-title">FileName</li>
    <li id="video-close-button">X</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The only disadvantage of `flexbox` is earlier [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), i.e. IE8. Though I didn't mention that in the question. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Yep, look for other answers if you need it to work on outdated browsers, see the support tables of flexbox here - http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox